# How to fix error “ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python.” when trying to install pyttsx3 using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\mayukh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Mayukh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f6rnjn5g\\pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Mayukh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f6rnjn5g\\pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Mayukh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6rnjn5g\pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\Mayukh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6rnjn5g\pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface\
Complete output (15 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mayukh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6rnjn5g\pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    Extension(
  File "C:\Users\Mayukh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6rnjn5g\pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface\pyobjc_setup.py", line 408, in Extension
    os_level = get_os_level()
  File "C:\Users\Mayukh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6rnjn5g\pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface\pyobjc_setup.py", line 218, in get_os_level
    pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
  File "c:\users\mayukh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\plistlib.py", line 99, in readPlist
    with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
  File "c:\users\mayukh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\mayukh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\plistlib.py", line 82, in _maybe_open
    with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while installing jupyterlab. I think you're using Python 3.8.x . Try to:

1. change your Python version from 3.8 to 3.6 by downloading the installer [Here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/)
2. Once you have finished the installation change your path from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\ to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts.
3. Change aswell the other one C:\Users\ricca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\ to C:\Users\ricca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\

Don't panic if the end of the directory that I wrote is different, just change the similar one. Hope my answer is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with python 3.7.7 when trying to install few python3 packages on my windows10 platform. I did add the variable to the path, but still did not work, then I tried the repair procedure that did not work either. Finally I had to uninstall and re install python 3.7.7 [not from the windows store, but from the official website]. After the re install, seemed to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

just install anaconda.navigator and get rid of all this hassle

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.